# add index column based on variable length rows

Tags: r, indexing, subset

This may be a simple question, but I have not been able to find an answer. My question is how to add an index column based on variable row lengths.  For example, in the below dataframe, I am trying to add a 3rd column, in which the index number increases each time there is a switch of sequence. Sample sequence 6:29 = Setnum 1, 34:50 = Setnum 2, 56:79 = Setnum 3, 84:100 = Setnum 4, etc.

```
Sample <- rep(c(6:29, 34:50, 56:79, 84:100, 106:129, 134:150), each=1, times=8)
set.seed(123)
randdf <- data.frame(area = round(rnorm(984, mean = 1000000, sd = 100000)), Sample)
```

What I hope to end up is a running count for each Sample sequence until the end of the dataframe regardless of the number of Sample sequence sets.

```
Sample   Setnum  area
6        1       
7        1       
...      1
29       1
34       2
35       2
...      2
50       2
...      3...5
134      6
135      6
...      6
150      6
6        7
7        7
...
134      8
135      8
```

The start and end numbers of each Sample sequence is the same. But the number of observations in each Sample sequence is not the same due to missing data.

I think I need to use 'split' at the beginning of each Sample sequence (6, 34, 56, 84, etc) and then 'cumsum'? Something to the effect of the code below:

```
cumsum(randdf[,1]=="6" | "34" | "56" | "84" | etc)
IndexDF <- split(randdf, cumsum(randf[,1]=="6"| etc))
## Setnum is the name of the index column
for(i in 1:length(IndexDF)) {IndexDF[[i]] <-cbind(IndexDF[[i]], 
Setnum=rep(i, nrow(IndexDF[[i]])))}
```

I hope my question is clear. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @agstudy answer, you need to do this:

```
randdf$Setnum  = cumsum(c(1,diff(randdf$Sample)!=1))
```

it will work only if there is a jump between the sample sizes, so the difference is not 1 when changing groups.

Comment: Thank you for your script! It works except that I was looking for the groups to counted cumulatively. As written, each group identified by the cut points is numbered 1 to 6 and repeats. How to count the cuts to unknown # of groups?

Comment: I didn't get the question, try this new one.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. I was struggling with this problem for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

This for example:

```
cumsum(c(1,diff(sample)!=1)+1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as a R newbie, I don't understand where and how to apply this code. It did not work as written. Is this supposed to replace the first or second line of my pseudocode?

Comment: Come on. You need just to assign this to a new data.frame variable. Whatever I see that the other answer add this assignment.